# kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet; Underlying Reason

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I have a modified linux on an ARM9 processor. It was working OK, but yesterday I got this error repeatedly:

```
kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
```

I have 2 questions:

- How can I find out what did cause the issue (The device has worked for more than a year without any problem)
- I did a bit research and I can fix the issue by temporarily increasing the size of table - `echo "5096" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_max`- and then re-programming the processor. How can I permanently increase the size of table?

**EDIT:** (Some more info)

- The output of `uname -mrs` : `Linux 2.6.30.9 armv5tejl`; The output of `cat /proc/version` : `Linux version 2.6.30.9 (ytian@softsrv1.iders.ca) (gcc version 4.4.1 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2009q3-67) ) #1 PREEMPT Thu Jan 23 11:58:19 CST 2014`.
  In addition, this distribution doesn't have `/etc/sysctl.conf`.
- I changed the traffic by looping back two physical Ethernet
  interfaces on my board and putting both of them on the same vlan to
  create a loop and crash the board. The `kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet` appeared exactly after this. Yet after
  disconnecting the loop, I keep getting the `kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet`. Can it be the reason (how can I make
  sure)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably a change in the traffic.

You can put an according entry in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 5096
```

See `man 5 sysctl.conf` and `man sysctl`.

Comment: Thx. The Linux doesn't have `/etc/sysctl.conf`, is there any other way?

Comment: @Aman I would guess that there must be some other way to set these kernel options then. But you haven't even told us which distro that is.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this website. The output of `uname -mrs` : `Linux 2.6.30.9 armv5tejl`; The output of `cat /proc/version` : `Linux version 2.6.30.9 (ytian@softsrv1.iders.ca) (gcc version 4.4.1 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2009q3-67) ) #1 PREEMPT Thu Jan 23 11:58:19 CST 2014`.